# Assigning colors to elements in a list, while plotting

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I have two list `x=[1,2,4]` and `y=[9,7,12]`. My list `x` contains certain elements from `df["ID"]` from the .csv table below.

```
df=(tabulate({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Age': [4, 15, 18, 6], 'Group': [3, 1, 9, 8], 'Color':['R', 'BL', 'G', 'G'] }, headers="keys", tablefmt='fancy_grid', missingval='N/A'))
```

| ID | Age | Group | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | R |
| 2 | 50 | 1 | BL |
| 3 | 18 | 9 | G |
| 4 | 6 | 8 | G |

I plotted `x` and `y` doing:
`plt.plot (x, y, 'o', color=('#ff0000'), label="Docu")`

But I want to plot each pair in their corresponding color. For example, the point `(1,9)` should be in red because R (red) is the color for `x=1`. Using the same logic, points `(2,7)` should be in black and  `(4,12)` should be in green.

I am thinking of using an IF statement to achieve this task. But I don't know where to start. Maybe there is even an easier way. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try... `color = ['red','black','green', 'green']`

Answer (score 0):

Well in direct plotting you can assign only 1 color to the 1 group.
If you want to plot every data point in separate color, Following might help. But let me warn you, this is not an efficient way to plot big data.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Age': [4, 15, 18, 6], 'Group': [3, 1, 9, 8], 'Color':['R', 'B', 'G', 'G'] })
```

```
0   1   4   3   R
1   2   15  1   B
2   3   18  9   G
3   4   6   8   G
```

created x and y, you can choose differently.

```
x = df['Age']
y = df['Group']
```

Defining color separately as in DF it is not proper,

```
color = ['red','black','green', 'green']
```

plotting

```
for i in range(len(df['Age'])):
    plt.plot (x[i], y[i], 'o', color=color[i])
```